# Calabi–Yau condition

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M$ is real $2n$-manifold with integrable complex structure.

Holomorphic triviality of canonical line bundle $K$ $\longleftrightarrow$ existence of a nowhere-vanishing section in $C^{\infty}(K)$.

Is it correct ? Or only one of conditions implies the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not correct.  The existence of a nowhere vanishing $C^\infty$ section of $K$ just means that $K$ is trivial as a smooth (or equivalently, topological) line bundle, which is weaker than being trivial as a holomorphic line bundle (for that, you would need a nowhere vanishing *holomorphic* section).

An example of a complex manifold whose canonical bundle is topologically trivial but not holomorphically trivial is a [hyperelliptic surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_surface).

Comment: Is it easy to construct a line bundle that is smoothly trivializable, but not holomorphic trivializable?

Comment: Sure.  For instance, take any nontrivial line bundle of degree $0$ on a smooth complete curve (topologically, line bundles are classified by their degree).